# Cremona group of $\mathbb{P}^n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

I know that the complex conjugation $\tau: \mathbb{P}^n \mapsto \mathbb{P}^n$ that sends any point $x$ to the point with complex conjugate coordinates $\tau(x)$ is a homeomorphism. In order to show that it isn't an automorphism of the algebraic variety of $\mathbb{P}^n$, I have to show that it doesn't belong to the Cremona group. But I can't describe the Cremona group of $\mathbb{P}^n$.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $\tau$ is equal to a birational transformation (or even a rational map) on a non-empty open subset $U\subset \mathbb{P}^n$ and find a contradiction.

For each $[z_0:\dots:z_n]\in U$ you would have
$$\tau([z_0:\dots:z_n])=[f_0(z_0,\dots,z_n):\dots:f_n(z_0,\dots,z_n)]$$
so you get $f_i(z_0,\dots,z_n) \overline{z_j}-f_j(z_0,\dots,z_n) \overline{z_i}_{|_U}=0$. It remains to see that this is only possible when both $f_i$ and $f_j$ are zero. For this, you can for example restrict to real points and then to points where one coordinate is not real.

Comment: Is it true that $\overline{z_i}=f_i(z_0,\dots,z_n)$?

Comment: If $\tau$ is equal to the rational map given by the $f_i$ then yes (up to multiple by a constant since we are in a projective space), but this is not possible in general.

Comment: So in this case, yes!

Answer (score 2):

There is no known usable description of the Cremona group when $n>2$. It is a very famous, long standing open problem.

Comment: So how I can proof that complex conjugation isn't an automorphism of the algebraic variety of $\mathbb{P}^n$?

Comment: You should use some other property that automorphisms have and your map does not. For example. conjugation is not even a regular map!

Comment: Cremona group is the group of birational automorphisms of $\mathbb{P}^n$, whereas the automorphism group of $\mathbb{P}^n$ is just $\mathbb{P}GL(n+1)$. So if you can show that $\tau(x)$ is not in $\mathbb{P}GL(n+1)$ then you are done.